SharePoint list - Change text vertical alignment to top in a column issue
I have a sharepoint online list with two columns.
The column Court/Sec is a single-choice with a few data. The column Excused is a multi-choice full of data.
I want to have the column Court/Sec with the text alignment on top of the row.
I tried with this JSON formatting on the column Court/Sec
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "table",
    "width": "100%"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "display": "table-cell",
        "vertical-align": "top"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I can see that the text is correctly aligned on top, only if the column Excused contains a few data, otherwise it is not well aligned. Here is a picture to explain better:

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Did you apply any JSON formatting for Excused column? If yes, can you provide JSON in your question?

Hello @GaneshSanap-MVP, thanks for your reply. There is no JSON applied to the Excused column. The only JSON is the one I wrote in my question and is applied to the Court/Sec column

I did a test and the text alignment on top of the row even if multi-choice full of data.
